# MySQL fallback multi language and different products

Tags: mysql, sql

**Basic package** can have languages 'de' and 'en'.

**Premium package** can have languages 'de' and 'en'.

In the basic package the customer cannot define his own texts. These are predefined by us *(in the languages 'de' and 'en')*

In the premium package, however, the customer can define his own texts **in some places**. *(again in the languages 'de' and 'en')*

With my two tables, I could now define the languages for both packages in the corresponding languages (4 entries per languagekey 'de - basic', 'en - basic', 'de-premium', 'en-premium'). But now I would like to define only the languages for the premium package, which are different than in the basic package. All other entries I want to take from this basic package. Like a fallback.

**Table**

languagedata

**Columns**

- languageid
- languagekey *(e.g. lng_message_nextteam)*

**Table**

languagetranslation

**Columns**

- languagetranslationid
- languageid *(is languageid from table languagedata)*
- translation *(the text in 'de' and 'en')*
- locale *(the lng code 'de' 'en')*
- inscapexproductid *(1 = basic / 2 = premium)*

```
SELECT languagekey, translation as languagevalue, locale, languagetranslation.inscapexproductid
FROM languagedata 
LEFT JOIN languagetranslation 
        ON languagedata.languageid  = languagetranslation.languageid
LEFT JOIN inscapexproducts 
        ON inscapexproducts.inscapexproductid = languagetranslation.inscapexproductid 
WHERE languagetranslation.locale = 'en' and languagetranslation.inscapexproductid = '2'
```

Quite close with this query. But how can I fill now the NULL values with the

```
SELECT languagekey, translation as languagevalue, locale, inscapexproductid 
FROM languagedata
LEFT JOIN languagetranslation 
        ON languagedata.languageid = languagetranslation.languageid AND languagetranslation.locale = 'en' AND languagetranslation.inscapexproductid = '2'
```

Here is the query I made for e.g. all texts in 'en' with the basic package. This works as expected.

But now my problem where I have no idea. If I have the premium package, then only some texts are different than in the basic package. And then I want a combination of the translations of the Premium (where entries are present) and all the others I want to take from the basic. there must be of course no duplicates.

I have already tried a few things with COALESCE or UNION. But I am not the MySQL professional.

Comment: Your first LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result. Move the languagetranslation conditions from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT RESULT.

Comment: Add another LEFT JOIN for the fallback language. Do COALESCE(lang1, fallbacklang).